# 'import sitecustomize' fails when opening spyder with non-empty file

Tags: python, spyder

I get the error message 
`'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback` in the internal python console in Spyder.

The interesting thing is, this only happens inside Spyder, running python in a shell doesn't show the same behaviour.

Furthermore, when I do

```
spyder --reset
```

It all works until I close Spyder during having any python file open in Spyder. After restart, the error message is shown again.

I saw the answer to ['import sitecustomize' failed upon starting spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258634/import-sitecustomize-failed-upon-starting-spyder). 
I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12 (64bit) and Spyder version 2.3.8 and not running a firewall, so this answer most probably doesn't fit to my case. Furthermore, setting the `DEBUG_SPYDER` variable to `True`, shows no errors related to this failed import.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be special characters in the path name of the current working-directory. Changing working-directories to a path without special characters before exiting spyder resolved the problem.