# importing numpy package in Spyder, Python

Tags: python, numpy, package

I'm starting to learn python. So the first thing I did was install python, in this case ubuntu 16.04 LTS, since in this system python is already installed.

As a first test, I tried to run a simple program with `numpy` library, but program n does not run, it displays the following error:

```
import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

It seems to me that Spyder failed to import the `numpy` library, although I've already called it by the terminal and it came, that is, it's installed.

My script is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 22 07:58:47 2019

@author: David
"""

import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])   
print(type(a))
```

Could someone please help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258634/import-sitecustomize-failed-upon-starting-spyder help you? Also you can simply try issuing `import numpy` in the interpreter on the right side of the screen to see if it'll complain.

Comment: Try `spyder --reset` then `spyder --default`. Good news is that your script actually works, it's just a Spyder problem!

Comment: Thanks @hqkhan and @Jacques Gaudin, the option `spyder --reset` then `spyder --default` work